# How can I save project specific settings to its own `.idea` folder?

Tags: phpstorm

I have two projects, one base on Drupal and the other base on Zend Frameworks, So they use different code styles.

I open two windows for each project. When I changed Drupal project settings to Drupal code style, the Zend project also changed.

How can I save project specific settings to its own `.idea` folder, so I can use different code sytles for each project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **"Manage"** button, select the code style and click **"Copy to project"**. Now your scheme will be set to "Project" and will be applied to this project **only**.

[image]

Unfortunately that is how it works right now (confusing, I agree).

Corresponding ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88210